# I'm duplicating list item elements and not sure how to correct

Tags: javascript

I am creating list item lines within a list item, inadvertently.   Such as (without content):

```
<li>
<li></li>
</li>
```

I can see it in the code but not sure how to fix.  First here is the html (pretty basic):

```
<ul class="list-group scrolltest" id="albumdetails"></ul>
```

The code:

```
function collapsedSubFolder(subFolderDetails, index) {
  console.log(subFolderDetails)
  var details = document.querySelector('#albumdetails')
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var subFolderLength = Object.keys(subFolderDetails).length
  var subFolderFiles = Object.keys(subFolderDetails);
  var subFolderFilePaths = Object.values(subFolderDetails);
  for (var i = 0; i < subFolderLength; ++i) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" id="sfflist"><a class="collapsedclass" href=/album' + encodeURI(subFolderFilePaths[i]) + '>' + subFolderFiles[i] + '</a href></li>';
        fragment.appendChild(li);
      }
  //myDiv.appendChild(fragment);
  details.insertBefore(fragment, details.children[index+1]);
```

When I realized what was happening - I removed the opening and closing li from my innerHTML, so above became -

```
  li.innerHTML = 'class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" id="sfflist"><a class="collapsedclass" href=/album' + encodeURI(subFolderFilePaths[i]) + '>' + subFolderFiles[i] + '</a href>'
```

Of course I found out that the `li tags` are closed when created my `innerHTML` is between `<li> </li>` I was hoping the `li` would have been opened, like  .

Hopefully this needs a minor adjustment.

Comment: `var li = document.createElement('li');` <- `li` is already an `<li>` element. You are then adding a child `<li>` by setting it in `innerHTML`. You can set the attributes via `li.id = 'sfflist` and `li.className = 'list-group-item list-group-item-info`

Comment: You aren't quoting your URL, which you probably should `href=/album' + encodeURI(subFolderFilePaths[i]) + '` -> `href="/album' + encodeURI(subFolderFilePaths[i]) + '"`. Also, closing tags shouldn't have properties `</a href>` -> `</a>`

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend assigning the same ID attribute in a loop. IDs should be unique

Comment: @Phil Ok, so I'm going to work on setting the attributes. As for the unique id's, they  links are generated dynamically so I supposed I could iterate a counter and tack it on, but overall it seems to work  fine.

Comment: @Phil, afaik, `++i` isn't a mistake,  I read somewhere that it is a faster way ;), but I'm being serious. The counter works , so not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was wrong calling it a mistake but it's certainly not _"faster"_

Comment: no, I thought I noticed an ever slight bump so I left it.  I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set attributes or properties directly on your `li` object, for example

```
// setting properties
li.id = 'sfflist'
li.className = 'list-group-item list-group-item-info'
// or setting attributes
li.setAttribute('id', 'sfflist')
```

I would continue to use the DOM methods rather than using `innerHTML`, eg

```
for (let i = 0; i < subFolderLength; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = `sfflist${i}` // make it unique
  li.className = 'list-group-item list-group-item-info'

  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = `/album${subFolderFilePaths[i]}`
  a.className = 'collapsedclass'
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(subFolderFiles[i]))

  li.appendChild(a)
  fragment.appendChild(li)
}
```

Comment: This one looks good, I need to implement but it makes sense.  ty!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `<li>` attributes via DOM too:

```
var li = document.createElement(...)
li.setAttribute('class','foo')
li.setAttribute('id','bar')
li.innerHTML = '<a class=...'
fragment.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Not sure how hackish this is, but `var tmp = context.createElement( "div" ); tmp.innerHTML = '<li ...'; fragment.appendChild(tmp.firstChild);` should  work, too